# The format of the XML JMeter jtl results file is not correct when running in distributed mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When I run my JMeter performance test in non-GUI mode with the command: `/jmeter -n -t TC_001_01.jmx -l result.jtl` an XML file is generated with the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<sample t="2045" it="3927" lt="0" ts="1468310751311" s="true" lb="Access Home Page Transaction" rc="200" rm="Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0" tn="Thread Group 1-1" ng="1" na="1">
<httpSample t="2045" it="0" lt="914" ts="1468310755221" s="true" lb="https://www.myserver.es" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" ng="1" na="1">
<assertionResult>
  <name>Response Assertion</name>
  <failure>false</failure>
  <error>false</error>
</assertionResult>
<httpSample t="914" it="0" lt="914" ts="1468310755221" s="true" lb="https://www.myserver.es/" rc="302" rm="Moved Temporarily" tn="Thread Group 1-1" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="1129" it="0" lt="386" ts="1468310756137" s="true" lb="https://www.myserver.es/home" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" ng="1" na="1"/>
</httpSample>
</sample>
...
```

When I run the same test adding the option **-r**: `/jmeter -n -t TC_001_01.jmx -l result.jtl -r` to start it using the master-slave (distributed) mode, following [Performance Testing in the Cloud with JMeter & AWS](https://www.artofsoftwaredevelopment.com/performance/performance-testing-in-the-cloud-with-jmeter-aws), the format of the output XML file is different:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<statSample>
<saveConfig>
<time>true</time>
<latency>true</latency>
<timestamp>true</timestamp>
<success>true</success>
<label>true</label>
<code>true</code>
.........
.........
</saveConfig>
<responseData></responseData>
<responseCode></responseCode>
.........
.........
</statSample>
```

How can I get JMeter to emit the first format of XML file when it is running in distributed mode?  (I have a XSLT template to generate an HTML report.)

I have reviewed the jmeter.properties and user.properties file without success. I am using jmeter 3.0 and jmeter-plugins-manager-0.8.

Comment: In my understanding, it is expected output. The format of reports generated in distributed mode and simple mode is EXPECTED to be different from each other. Distributed mode reports provide additional info w.r.t each JMeter slave. SImilary, If you are using multiple threadgroups in your test plan then you also need to update this variable (for distributed mode) jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true

Comment: I have run the same test using my laptop as slave and master, and I get the correct xml format. So, seems to be something related with the AWS configuration I am using, maybe with the ssh tunnel, rmi ports...

Comment: You have tried the same within your local network? using two different machines? Results should be same. I have worked with AWS and never faced any different behavior. Reports should be same for distributed mode. Doesnot matter if it is on AWS or local network.

Comment: The format is the same if running in the same subnet, not when running in different subnets.

1-A) Start an slave in AWS, add into jmeter.properties: 
server_port=24001
server.rmi.localhostname=127.0.0.1
server.rmi.localport=26001
1-B) Start the slave: ./jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1

2.For the master:
2.A) Open the ssh tunnel, add into jmeter.properties:
remote_hosts=127.0.0.1:24001 
client.rmi.localport=25000
mode=Statistical
2.B) Run: export JVM_ARGS="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"

Run the test: "jmeter -n -t TC.jmx -r  -l output.jtl"

Comment: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Ok, at the end I got it. Instead of using mode=Statistical, I set it to mode:Standard and that solve my problem.

Thanks!!